# Suggest me a suitable adapter to pass arraylist containing image url and title to display in listview

Tags: android

i hav to display the thumbnail of the image along with the title of it in a list view by parsing the JSON feed.. My code

```
public class Main extends ListActivity{

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listplaceholder);

    String url;
    Bitmap bitmap;
    ImageView img;
    int im ;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();      

    JSONObject json =  Json_mysamActivity.getJSONfromURL("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/mobile/videos?max-results=3&alt=json");        

    try {
        JSONObject jb = json.getJSONObject("feed");         
        JSONArray jarr = jb.getJSONArray("entry");
        for(int i=0;i<jarr.length();i++){                       
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();    
            JSONObject e = jarr.getJSONObject(i);
            JSONObject det = e.getJSONObject("title");
            map.put("id",  String.valueOf(i));
            map.put("$t", "t:" + det.getString("$t"));
            map.put("type", "type: " +  det.getString("type"));


            JSONObject det1 = e.getJSONObject("media$group");
            JSONArray det12 = det1.getJSONArray("media$thumbnail");
            for(int j=0;j<1;j++)
            {
                JSONObject det12obj = det12.getJSONObject(i);
                url = det12obj.getString("url");
        map.put("url", "url:"+ det12obj.getString("url"));

                mylist.add(map);
            }

        }       

    } catch (JSONException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }        

    String[] from = new String[] { "$t", "type","url" };
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.item_title, R.id.item_subtitle, R.id.test_image };
    MySimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new MySimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.main, mylist , 
    from, to);

    setListAdapter(adapter);
    final ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);  
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {              
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            HashMap<String, String> o = (HashMap<String, String>) lv.getItemAtPosition(position);                   
            Toast.makeText(Main.this, "ID '" + o.get("id") + "' was clicked.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 

        }
    });
}
public class MySimpleCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {
// SimpleCursorAdapter requires cursor in the place of ArrayList but I need to pass //arraylist, how should I implement it
        public MySimpleCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist,
            String[] from, int[] to) {
            super(context, layout, mylist, from, to);
        }

    @Override
    public void setViewImage(ImageView v, String url) {

        String path =url ;
        Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
        v.setImageBitmap(b);

    }

}
}
```

Comment: Take more time to edit properly your next questions. Thanks @Lucifer

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a [SimpleAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html). A cursor adapter is used for displaying daat in a list that comes from a database. SimpleAdapter is used for data in RAM (your list after parsing the json).

Check this first [google entry](http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.fr/2008/03/my-first-meeting-with-simpleadapter.html), it should do.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using arraylist as datasource you should use ArrayAdapter, so Extend your adapter from ArrayAdapter. see link for Custom Array Adapter:

http://android-er.blogspot.in/2010/06/custom-arrayadapter-with-with-different.html

When you are loading image views in list, its good practice to use LazyLoading, see below link for Lazy Loading in android:

http://ballardhack.wordpress.com/2010/04/05/loading-remote-images-in-a-listview-on-android/

Answer (score 0):

for this you have to use LayoutInflater, write your own adapter class extends ArrayAdapter,

mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, R.layout.list_row, R.id.title, data,
                mInflater, imgid);